# Forcing specific .NET types in JScript.NET?

Tags: fiddler, jscript, jscript.net

I am using the Fiddler web debugger which uses [FiddlerScript](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-fiddlerscript) which is based on JScript.NET. I'm trying to do some simple .NET string parsing but it fails with error "**More than one method or property matches this argument list**". For example:

```
        var ahraw: String = "one, two, three, four";
        var ah: Array = ahraw.Split([',', ' '], System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (var i in ah) {
            FiddlerObject.alert("\"" + ah[i] + "\"");
        }
```

[image]

[String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split) has these prototypes:

```
Split(Char[], Int32, StringSplitOptions)
Split(String[], Int32, StringSplitOptions)
Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)
Split(Char[], StringSplitOptions)
Split(Char[], Int32)
Split(Char[])
```

Even if I add an Int32 and run it like `ahraw.Split([',', ' '], 99, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` or `ahraw.Split(", ", 99, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` it still finds multiple methods. Is it possible to force the specific .NET type? Something like `var sep: String` doesn't work either.

Of course there are other ways to split a string in JScript such as split() (note the lowercase s). I'm more interested in how I can get around this issue for when there's no javascript equivalent for the function I need to call, so I have to call a .NET funciton.

Comment: May be this is just not possible with JScript.net. Have you tried to use C# instead of JScript.net (can be changed in the Options dialog of Fiddler).

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, these days it would probably be easier to just use C# as a scripting language (could be set in `Tools -> Options -> Scripting -> Language`).

If you however have/want to stick to JScript.NET (e.g. if you already have complex customizations), you can work around the problem by declaring [typed array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/5kas1c51%28v%3Dvs.100%29) for the separators, otherwise the compiler cannot distinguish which of the `Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)` and `Split(Char[], StringSplitOptions)` overloads to call.

```cs
    var ahraw: String = "one, two, three, four";
    var separators: Char[] = [',', ' '];
    var ah: Array = ahraw.Split(separators, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (var i in ah) {
        FiddlerObject.alert("\"" + ah[i] + "\"");
    }
```

Comment: This is the right answer. I was doing `var separators: String = ", ";` but I should have been doing  `var separators: String[] = [", "];`